# Вывести текст из файла JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Хочу сделать функцию, которая возвращает текст из файла, что я делаю не так?
В консоль выводится `Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function`

```js
function sendGetRequest(url) {
  return fetch(url).then(response => {
    return response.text();
  });
}

async function getTextInUrl(url) {
  let result;
  const text = await sendGetRequest(url)
    .then(data => {
      result = data;
      console.log(result);
    });
  return result;

}

const a = await getTextInUrl('frag.glsl');
console.log(a);
```

Comment: А что в консоле?

Comment: Ты это так локальный файл тянешь? [если да, глянь](https://github.com/b5414/readFileAsync)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const url = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(['Текст из файла'], { type: 'text/plain' }))

function sendGetRequest(url) {
  return fetch(url).then(response => {
    return response.text();
  });
}

async function getTextInUrl(url) {
  let result = await sendGetRequest(url)
  result += '\n\nДобавим текста'
  return result
}

void async function () {
  console.log(
    await getTextInUrl(/*'frag.glsl'*/url)
  )
}()
```

Comment: что значит `void async function(){'code'}()`? и почему не работает `void async (function(){'code'})()` ?

Comment: @МихаилКамахин то же, что и `(()=>{code})()`. Просто вызвать `await getTextInUrl`, можно вызвать только из асинхронной функции. `void`, говорит о том что эта функция ничего не возвращает и позволяет не окружать скобками.

Comment: @МихаилКамахин upd: а `URL.createObjectURL` надеюсь это понятно - эмуляция реального запроса, чтоб можно было воспроизвести на SO

Answer (score 1):

Сделай так, вместо 2 последних строк:

```
(async()=>{
    const a = await getTextInUrl('frag.glsl');
    console.log(a);
})();
```

Вот твой код

```js
const sendGetRequest=(url)=>{
    return fetch(url).then((r)=>{
        return response.text();
    });
};

const getTextInUrl=async(url)=>{
    const result = await sendGetRequest(url).then((r)=>{
        // console.log(r);
        return r;
    });
    return result;
};

const start=async()=>{
    const a = await getTextInUrl('frag.glsl');
    console.log(a);
};
start();
```

Вот "мой" код

```js
(async()=>{
    const result = await fetch('frag.glsl').then((res)=>(res.text()));
    console.log(result);
})();
```

Comment: @МихаилКамахин я оставил чать кода, чтобы тебе было удобно handlить его